# ASp.net find checks

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET. I am working on live website here is the website
http://city-flat.com/

Issue is this i don't know where its functionality come from. i have found it in all directories. but i don't find c# code.

Example:
When i logged-in the navigation bar change from "Login to My account" menu. but how i can found where is this check. Whenever on home.aspx have simple this code for navigation

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hi-icon-effect-1 hi-icon-effect-1a">

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hi-icon help" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="lnkHeaderCMS">Help <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <asp:ListView ID="lstHeaderMenus" runat="server">
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                        </LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <li><a href='<%# Eval("sURL")%>'><%# Eval("sName")%></a></li>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:ListView>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li runat="server" contentidmode="Static" id="liLogin"><a href="/Login" class="LBL_SIGN_IN  hi-icon"><span class="login"></span>Login</a></li>
                            <li runat="server" contentidmode="Static" id="liRegister"><a href="/Register" class="LBL_SIGN_UP hi-icon"><span class="signup"></span>Sign Up</a></li>

                            <li class="semiactive"><a href="/List-Your-Space" class="LBL_LIST_YOUR_SPACE listspace">List Your Space</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown" runat="server" contentidmode="Static" id="liMyAccount" visible="false">
                                <a style="padding-left: 60px;" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle myaccount" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <img src="/uploadfiles/noProfileImage.jpg" alt="" class="imgProfilePic" style="position: absolute; left: 12px; top: 0; height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 50%;">
                                    <span class="LBL_MY_ACCOUNT">My Account</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="/Dashboard" class="LBL_DASHBOARD_TEXT dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Inbox"><span class="LBL_INBOX">Inbox</span>&nbsp;<span class="badge messagesBadge  hide"><span class="unreadmessages"></span>&nbsp;<span class="BTN_NEW_TEXT">-</span></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Your-Listings" class="LBL_YOUR_LISTINGS listing">Your Listings</a></li>                                        
                                    <li><a href="#" class="LBL_WISH_LIST WishList">Wish Lists</a></li>
                                    <%--<li><a href="#" class="LBL_GROUPS">Groups</a></li>--%>
                                    <li><a href="/Invite-Friends"><span class="LBL_INVITE_FRIENDS invitefriend">Invite Friends</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/My-Profile" class="LBL_EDIT_PROFILE_MNGMT_TITLE profile">Edit Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/My-Account" class="LBL_ACCOUNT account">Account</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/List-Your-Space" class="LBL_LIST_YOUR_SPACE listspace">List Your Space</a></li>
                                    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" CssClass="LBL_LOGOUT_TEXT" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click">LogOut</asp:LinkButton></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
```

There is no check simply working base on ID's.

How i can find .cs files?

Any idea please?

****EDIT****
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll find a `+` symbol for your every `.aspx` page which when expanded you will see a `.cs` page for every `.aspx` page.. That's where your backend server code exists..

Comment: There are no any + symbol. There are just aspx files. And in Bin directory there are some .dll and .pdb file.

Comment: in which editor i can see + symbol with .aspx file?

Comment: how i can find .cs file?

Comment: what editor you are using??

Comment: I am using dreamwearver.

Comment: Try using Visual Studio instead...

Comment: have some alternative? i don't have visual studio right now.

Comment: Locate the physical path of file then in the system.. I hope there you can find `.cs` files.. If you don't find there too then you have compiled version of the project.. where `.cs` will be built into `dll`s

Comment: yes  i have .dll and .pdb files in bin directory. mean its compiled version? Right?

Comment: are you sure it has `.aspx` files?

Comment: yes it has .aspx files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94578/discussion-between-farrukh-zaman-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Are you sure you were browsing the source code? From your screenshots, it looks like you are browsing the compiled app directories. It is because .NET will compile all .cs files into DLL during build/publish. If you are working in a company, usually the source code is stored in source control, not FTP server.